# PIC32MX170F256B SPI

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi

I bought a PIC32MX170F256B but struggle with the SPI module. The chip has dedicated pins for the clock but no clock is present after writing to the SPI1BUF register.

The UART is working, the timers are working, but no SPI CLK on pin 26 or on pin 25.

I can toggle the pin (pin 25) but I can't find any more
info in the specific datsheet (SPI or overall datasheet).

Can someone answer my question or does someone have code that can solve my problem?

Comment: Without any details it could be a problem in line 42 of main.c or a bent IO pin. Try to add relevant info what you have done so others can see what is wrong in your code and hardware.

Comment: is the peripheral enabled?
is the peripheral clock enabled?
is the pin muxing set correctly?
is the peripheral configured correctly? As a master?
there should be library functions to do this for you.